# np.random.randn refuses to take negative arguments

Tags: python, numpy, random, valueerror

```
import numpy as np
a=[2,4,6,-1,4]
#b=[np.random.randn(0,2) for i in a[1:]]
#print(b)
b=[np.random.randn(x,y) for x, y in zip(a[1:], a[1:])]
print(b)
```

OUTPUT

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-34-b2077da31d55> in <module>()
      3 #b=[np.random.randn(0,2) for i in a[1:]]
      4 #print(b)
----> 5 b=[np.random.randn(x,y) for x, y in zip(a[1:], a[1:])]
      6 b

<ipython-input-34-b2077da31d55> in <listcomp>(.0)
      3 #b=[np.random.randn(0,2) for i in a[1:]]
      4 #print(b)
----> 5 b=[np.random.randn(x,y) for x, y in zip(a[1:], a[1:])]
      6 b

mtrand.pyx in mtrand.RandomState.randn()

mtrand.pyx in mtrand.RandomState.standard_normal()

mtrand.pyx in mtrand.cont0_array()

ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed
```

the error keeps throwing no matter whatever a[x1:x2] i give .

What is the obvious thing i am missing ?

I am fairly new to numpy , so please dont mind if this is very basic .

Comment: Why are you trying to give it a negative value?  You many need to reread what the parameters are for this function.

Comment: What kind of random number are you trying to create, currently you are doing `randn(4, 4)` and `rand(6, 6)` which creates 2 dimensional square matrices of size `4` and `6` respectively. What do you expect a 2 dimensional square matrix of size `-1` to give?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Part of writing a good question is explaining what you're trying to accomplish. Right now, we only have the result you're getting, not the result you're hoping for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation for [numpy.Random.randn](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html)

> The dimensions of the returned array, **should be all positive**. If no argument is given a single Python float is returned.

You're mistaking the arguments that control the dimensions of the array(s) for the upper and lower bounds of your random numbers. Since an array can't have a negative index, using negative numbers for the dimensions of the array isn't allowed.

You weren't clear on what you were trying to accomplish in your question, but it seems like you want an array of random numbers between an upper and lower boundary. Instead, your current implementation is creating a 2 dimensional array that's 2x2, 4x4, etc.

Comment: Thank you, but really this is a question that could've been avoided if the OP had looked through the docs themselves. I'm not even sure what it is they're trying to do here.